# Do I need more RAM?

Tags: macos, memory, macos-bigsur

I have an iMac 2020 with 32GB RAM.

My question is if i need more memory, because I'm confused about the indicators of activity monitor, as shown below. If there is 'Swap used', does it mean the available RAM is insufficient and the machine would benefit from adding more RAM?

Because nowadays RAM is not expensive, I want to maximize the performance so I can add more 32GB if needed.

[image]

Comment: "if there is 'Swap used', does it means the available RAM is insufficient" - no

Comment: If you specify exactly which iMac model number it is, we could tell you if it can be expanded beyond 32 GB. Some can, some can't.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's the Imac 2020, it can go up to 128GB RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot used, apps and ["wired" memory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349037/30gb-out-of-32gb-being-used-for-wired-memory) using around 25GB, but you have nearly nothing using your swap file at only 400MB used.

If you had a significant amount of swap used then that would be a sign that memory is your problem, but low swap usage suggests that buying more more is not a high priority for your system.

The "wired" memory being high suggests to me that you just need to reboot your computer.

Comment: Thanks but why system would use swap if there is enough 'real' memory available ?

Comment: Virtual memory uses a lot of different conditions to determine when to swap. Some are time based, some are memory pressure based and others are "push stuff out to the page file but keep in memory at the same time". Linux has a ["swappiness"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277021) which will essentially pre-fill swap space allowing the system to simply free memory blocks when under pressure as they are already written to disk. Some swap usage is normal, only if you had tens of gigabytes in use then I would consider your system "memory starved". Yours seems normal to me.

Comment: The swap having been used could indicate that at some time in the past you were using considerably more RAM, which has since been reclaimed. The swap reading tends to hang around for a very long time afterwards & eventually shrinks [why, I've no idea, but it does]. As Mokubai says, you have zero issues there. Basically, so long as that bar on the left stays green, you're not memory-starved. The occasional shift to amber is no worry either. Only if you spend half your life in amber or red should you seriously start to think about more RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just in case, i'll add more 32GB :-D